# can we pass "e" from one function to another in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written one function like:

```
 var link = {
       login : "#log_In"
    };

    var onLogin = function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

      //login functionality
    }

    var clickMe = function(){
       onLogin();//error can not read property of undefined "e is undefined"
    }

   var onClickFunction = {
          login : clickMe
    };
```

Now when i click like:

```
$(SELECTORS.link[key]).click(onClickFunction[key]);
```

I tried passing e to clickMe function and send that e to onLogin() still get  "e is undefined". How should i pass this "e"??

Comment: Why are you making a separate function for `clickMe` and `onLogin`?  Why not just put `onLogin` in the `onClickFunction` data structure?

Comment: just to see things clearly and build code not complex. My code for onLogin is itself around 50LOC. that is why ..

Comment: But, I'm asking you why you're creating a 2nd function when the first one would work just fine.  Why are you creating a second function name?  Two functions that do the same thing is more complex than just using the same function name in both places.

Comment: I want uuid which comes after onLogin() completes. To access the uuid i need to move to other page js, that is one way.Or i can access the uuid in this page itself . So I wrote function clickMe which call onLogin() ..

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand anything in that last comment.

Comment: Your code as shown couldn't get as far as the line where you say there is an error: `onClickFunction.login` will be `undefined` because you don't give `clickMe` a value until *after* trying to use it in the `onClickFunction` object literal. Have you changed the order of your code when you pasted it into the question?

Comment: Why not just use `var onClickFunction = {login : onLogin};`?

Answer (score 2):

You are pointing to the handler correctly, you just need to relay the arguments.

```
var link = {
   login : "#log_In"
};
var onClickFunction = {
    login : clickMe
};

var onLogin = function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

  //login functionality
};

var clickMe = function(){
    // relay the arguments to the handler onLogin
   onLogin.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
};


$(SELECTORS.link[key]).click(onClickFunction[key]);
```

- convert `arguments` to a proper array
- use `apply` to pass them to the handler `onLogin`

Comment: is there any browser compatibility issue with this function?? i need to run my code on older version browsers.

Comment: It's vanilla JS, so probably not.  You'll have to test it, though.

Comment: i mean its not compatible with other browsers. sorry if you misunderstood.

Comment: @ajayv Good to know.  ;)